# Python requests hangs on read

Tags: python, python-requests, http-get

I am using Python 3.7.3 and I'm trying to GET a gif:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://track.hubspot.com", allow_redirects=True)
```

This code hangs, apparently indefinitely.

```
import requests
requests.get("https://track.hubspot.com", allow_redirects=True, timeout=0.1)
```

This code throws an error in read: `ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='track.hubspot.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)`

If I visit it in my browser, I successfully load the 1x1 gif at the target. `urllib3` and `wget` (the command-line tool, not the Python library) also hang. Is there a way to use Python to GET the address without the arbitrary timeout and the error?

Comment: Does using timeout=10 or something help?

Comment: Yes, timeout causes it to raise an error, but the action at the other end of the connection (on the hubspot.com side) does take place. If the timeout is too short, I get a ConnectTimeout and the action at the other end does not take place. I'm not sure how short I can can safely make the timeout. 10 is definitely too long for production.

Comment: The code worked for me.

Comment: Huh, thanks @tdelaney! I tried in a fresh instance of python and it still doesn't work for me...

Comment: Perhaps it does rate limiting and you have to wait.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'm pretty sure I won't be triggering rate limits because it's intended to be a high-frequency access target and I've only hit it manually - so < 25 times in the last 24 hours - and it's never worked (except in browser)

Comment: What `requests` version are you using?

Comment: @phil version 2.21.0

Comment: Huh. Can't recreate. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me `response = requests.get('https://track.hubspot.com')`
You should consider using a context manager.

```py
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("https://track.hubspot.com")
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps for a single request.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you guys... I'm using Python 3.7.3 and even the context-manager approach is still failing for me. I'm sorry I can't get you a consistent minimal broken example!

Comment: @tdelaney Probably not but I'm not sure how many requests there are. Also, just for my own knowledge, is there any downside to using one?

Comment: @MarkC. I'm using python 3.9.0 if that helps

Comment: Oh nice, thanks @phil

Comment: @MarkC. Also `requests` version 2.26.0

Comment: Upgrading Python now.

Comment: A session can do connection pooling and you can configure security once and use it multiple places. It doesn't help for a single request, though.