# Selenium succeeding, python requests library failing, despite same url and same request headers - what's the difference?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, http-headers

```
# selenium-request.py

from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.cmegroup.com/content/cmegroup/en/tools-information/advisorySearch/jcr:content/full-par/cmeadvisorysearch.advisorySearch.advisorynotices:Advisory%20Notices.-.2.12|07|2021.01|01|2008.json')

for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(request.response.headers)
```

When I run that code I get the headers Selenium uses:

```
$ python selenium-request.py
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://star-website.com
Content-Type: application/json
ETag: W/"36b8a-5d3d28ed9cc43"
Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Dec 2021 16:16:16 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Server: Apache
ServerID: e1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Date: Thu, 23 Dec 2021 16:16:16 GMT
Content-Length: 46236
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.cmegroup.com *.quikstrike.net commodex.co.il openexchange.community.cmegroup.com staging.tickertocker.com http://www.straitsfinancial.com www.straitsfinancial.com http://straitsfinancial.com https://www.home.saxo https://app.topsteptrader.com https://help.topsteptrader.com https://staging.topsteptrader.com https://blueeditsitecore.sys.dom https://bluesitecore.sys.dom https://sitecoredev.orange.saxobank.com https://sitecoredev-nocache.orange.saxobank.com https://sitecoredevedit.orange.tst2.dom http://star-website.com https://www.investing.com https://*.benzinga.com https://bz.zingbot.bz https://www.zingbot.bz https://gdcdyn.interactivebrokers.com https://www.interactivebrokers.com https://zingbot.bz https://www.zingbot.bz https://m.zingbot.bz https://bz.zingbot.bz https://dev.futuresfirstacademy.com https://uat.futuresfirstacademy.com https://futuresfirstacademy.com http://stage.barchart.com http://www.barchart.com https://www.infinityfutures.com https://kilofutures.com https://m.cqg.com https://mdemo.cqg.com *.chicago.cme.com:7822 https://uatm.cqg.com https://local.zingbot.bz https://www.gulfbondsukuk.org www.kgieworld.sg https://www.propex24.wpcomstaging.com https://www.propex24.com *.straitsfinancial.gate39tech.com us.straitsfinancial.com https://*.kapcoclients.com https://kapcoclients.com https://*.wallstreetbound.org https://wallstreetbound.org https://cofcointl.plateau.com https://rise.articulate.com https://members.tradeday.com http://blf-django.herokuapp.com https://www.bluelinefutures.com https://www.bluelinefutures.live https://www.bluelinefutures.trade https://login.chicago.cme.com https://loginnr.chicago.cme.com https://logincert.chicago.cme.com https://login-ny.chicago.cme.com https://ampfutures.com https://cme.ampfutures.com https://*.advantagefutures.com https://*.e-futures.com https://*.etrade.com https://*.gffbrokers.com https://infinityfutures-cn.com https://sweetfutures.com https://*.tradovate.com https://home.saxo https://*.tickmill.co.uk https://*.directa.it https://big.pt https://*.tradestation-international.com https://*.stonex.com http://tradinglesson.com https://tradinglesson.com *.ibroker.it *.ibroker.es *.cornertrader.ch *.whselfinvest.com *.banxbroker.de *.ameritrade.com *.sweetfutures.com  *.danielstrading.com  *.gainfutures.com  *.futuresonline.com *.tdainc.com *.lsvp.com *.schwab.com *.schwab.co.uk *.us.global.schwab.com *.dev.schwab.com;
Set-Cookie: ak_bmsc=AB0A9701302106EABE2E195C6AC2A074~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQLtERAvOZVN19AQAA7C8U6A7AWr7StAmiphZPltguFftPSOXgfa2NAq7Vts+40k7AdnPG55ULK1vyBRhPRdqWbtYml3JTC3RjHLu31l8kWBFvysYyuY2uz4GpkvmOWoBSN/Dl/2bQ9bEgbiYj3tCZ1o+wEvMfsiAWiJeMY3M1ozu6nyQz0JVpdvfsqun3z5wGhpJWhkjrJjeIyHvVdzx2uyIb1azRFlHT+nRCR6NHGoaMM/G2sI1DqPOXPB5btXjdncvB739c2Beh7RgWD/zvb78qpAJDUR1KOenDy1EwN2Bg8pqH1sxlsoVrl7i7r/pAOaWKfd4U1FKP7p730GfOp/m2VRBIdYgHDPHPvGeITPKrR/G22aR886r9Lerhug==; Domain=.cmegroup.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 18:16:01 GMT; Max-Age=7185; HttpOnly
```

I copy these exact headers into a python dict and request as follows:

```
# python-request.py
import requests

headers = {
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://star-website.com",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "ETag": 'W/"36b8a-5d3d28ed9cc43"',
    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 23 Dec 2021 16:16:16 GMT",
    "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "Server": "Apache",
    "ServerID": "e1",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=86400",
    "Date": "Thu, 23 Dec 2021 16:16:16 GMT",
    "Content-Length": "46236",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' *.cmegroup.com *.quikstrike.net commodex.co.il openexchange.community.cmegroup.com staging.tickertocker.com http://www.straitsfinancial.com www.straitsfinancial.com http://straitsfinancial.com https://www.home.saxo https://app.topsteptrader.com https://help.topsteptrader.com https://staging.topsteptrader.com https://blueeditsitecore.sys.dom https://bluesitecore.sys.dom https://sitecoredev.orange.saxobank.com https://sitecoredev-nocache.orange.saxobank.com https://sitecoredevedit.orange.tst2.dom http://star-website.com https://www.investing.com https://*.benzinga.com https://bz.zingbot.bz https://www.zingbot.bz https://gdcdyn.interactivebrokers.com https://www.interactivebrokers.com https://zingbot.bz https://www.zingbot.bz https://m.zingbot.bz https://bz.zingbot.bz https://dev.futuresfirstacademy.com https://uat.futuresfirstacademy.com https://futuresfirstacademy.com http://stage.barchart.com http://www.barchart.com https://www.infinityfutures.com https://kilofutures.com https://m.cqg.com https://mdemo.cqg.com *.chicago.cme.com:7822 https://uatm.cqg.com https://local.zingbot.bz https://www.gulfbondsukuk.org www.kgieworld.sg https://www.propex24.wpcomstaging.com https://www.propex24.com *.straitsfinancial.gate39tech.com us.straitsfinancial.com https://*.kapcoclients.com https://kapcoclients.com https://*.wallstreetbound.org https://wallstreetbound.org https://cofcointl.plateau.com https://rise.articulate.com https://members.tradeday.com http://blf-django.herokuapp.com https://www.bluelinefutures.com https://www.bluelinefutures.live https://www.bluelinefutures.trade https://login.chicago.cme.com https://loginnr.chicago.cme.com https://logincert.chicago.cme.com https://login-ny.chicago.cme.com https://ampfutures.com https://cme.ampfutures.com https://*.advantagefutures.com https://*.e-futures.com https://*.etrade.com https://*.gffbrokers.com https://infinityfutures-cn.com https://sweetfutures.com https://*.tradovate.com https://home.saxo https://*.tickmill.co.uk https://*.directa.it https://big.pt https://*.tradestation-international.com https://*.stonex.com http://tradinglesson.com https://tradinglesson.com *.ibroker.it *.ibroker.es *.cornertrader.ch *.whselfinvest.com *.banxbroker.de *.ameritrade.com *.sweetfutures.com  *.danielstrading.com  *.gainfutures.com  *.futuresonline.com *.tdainc.com *.lsvp.com *.schwab.com *.schwab.co.uk *.us.global.schwab.com *.dev.schwab.com;",
    "Set-Cookie": "ak_bmsc=AB0A9701302106EABE2E195C6AC2A074~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQLtERAvOZVN19AQAA7C8U6A7AWr7StAmiphZPltguFftPSOXgfa2NAq7Vts+40k7AdnPG55ULK1vyBRhPRdqWbtYml3JTC3RjHLu31l8kWBFvysYyuY2uz4GpkvmOWoBSN/Dl/2bQ9bEgbiYj3tCZ1o+wEvMfsiAWiJeMY3M1ozu6nyQz0JVpdvfsqun3z5wGhpJWhkjrJjeIyHvVdzx2uyIb1azRFlHT+nRCR6NHGoaMM/G2sI1DqPOXPB5btXjdncvB739c2Beh7RgWD/zvb78qpAJDUR1KOenDy1EwN2Bg8pqH1sxlsoVrl7i7r/pAOaWKfd4U1FKP7p730GfOp/m2VRBIdYgHDPHPvGeITPKrR/G22aR886r9Lerhug==; Domain=.cmegroup.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 18:16:01 GMT; Max-Age=7185; HttpOnly"
}


requests.get(
    "https://www.cmegroup.com/content/cmegroup/en/tools-information/advisorySearch/jcr:content/full-par/cmeadvisorysearch.advisorySearch.advisorynotices:Advisory%20Notices.-.2.12|07|2021.01|01|2008.json",
    headers=headers)
```

When I run this it just hangs indefinitely, so there is some issue with the request.

Apart from the headers, what is the difference between the requests made by python and Selenium - how could I identify the issue and hopefully get this working with the python requests library?

**Update**

I updated the code to get the `request.headers` instead:

```
Host: www.cmegroup.com
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

... but the python requests script has the same result when using these headers, just hanging (or timing out if I set a timeout parameter).

**Further update**

Debug output is as follows:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.cmegroup.com:443
send: b'GET /content/cmegroup/en/tools-information/advisorySearch/jcr:content/full-par/cmeadvisorysearch.advisorySearch.advisorynotices:Advisory%20Notices.-.2.12%7C07%7C2021.01%7C01%7C2008.json HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nHost: www.cmegroup.com\r\nsec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: Linux\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: none\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\nSec-Fetch-User: ?1\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it only needs a compatible User-Agent header.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0',
}

url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/content/cmegroup/en/tools-information/advisorySearch/jcr:content/full-par/cmeadvisorysearch.advisorySearch.advisorynotices:Advisory%20Notices.-.2.12|07|2021.01|01|2008.json'

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout = 30) # A
print(response.status_code)    # Prints 200 (OK).
print(response.json())         # Prints the output as JSON. "item" key has 50 values in a list.
```

^ This snippet did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, seems AWS IP address range is blocked, otherwise this snippet working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks, you are using the response headers, not request headers.
Try

```
print(request.headers)
```

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. I updated the script to use the `request.headers` instead though and it's still behaving the same.

Comment: @Tim_B I see your updates.
Just adding some investigation results.. I've tried to execute your GET request with your selenium request headers using Postman (sorry, not able to try with python) and it works. So, you've got the valid selenium headers.

Comment: You may try to add logs to your request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836/5226491.

Comment: thanks, added logs as requested using the method you provided a link to

Comment: Not sure, but you may try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69923105/5226491. It may be related to your python and requests versions.

Comment: Gave this a try but no luck, thanks for the suggestion